# CSS Unequal Image Height

Tags: html, css, visual-composer

I have a 3 column grid, of different widths, which contain an image element each.

[image]

The structure is essentially

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3"><img></div>
    <div class="col-6"><img></div>
    <div class="col-3"><img></div>
</div>
```

Each image is set to:

```
img {
  display:block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Each column also contains padding-left and padding-right of 15px;

This however causes the middle **col-6** column to be taller than the other two columns in the row.

I have tried to double the left- and right-padding for the longer the **col-6** column but I don't think this is ideal and also does not work responsively.

I have also tried using flexbox to no avail.

What is the best solution to keep all images the same height and still work responsively?

Comment: Is it possible you can make a pen or fiddle? the following html and css does not display the image you have in your question?

Comment: Isn't the problem that the image in the middle column is the wrong size? Couldn't you solve it by making it 10 or so pixels shorter?

Comment: Given the visual it appears to really be one image repeated on the larger.  Set the background image in CSS on the div and set "repeat" true perhaps? `background-repeat: repeat-x; background-image: url("http://www.example.com/bck.png");`

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it, there is a logical gutter in the center of the middle column. `col-6` is **not** exactly twice the width of `col-3`. Rather, it is twice the width *plus* the gutter width (had there been two `col-3`s instead of a `col-6`).

[image: Example showing the gutter between each col-3, which should also be included in the width of a col-6]

This extra width means that if you merely take the dimensions of a `col-3` image and then double the width, the image will have to *grow* to fit the slightly wider space. This is why it is sticking out a little further.

So, don't worry so much about the CSS. Just use an image of the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use these images as background of your divs? As backgrounds you can use `cover` and these images won't affect the div's sizes.

If it doesn't help, please, create a plunker to let me test with you.

```
.div-with-bg {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to propositional resize of image in bootstrap grid. It has three possible solutions.

1. make image size equal to bootstrap grid size by cropping.(so your image in **col-6** should be **(col-3)*2 + 30px(gutter size)**).
2. Use images in background in div with fixed height and width.
3. Use dynamic image crop library to keep them equal in size.